# Why would updates to a paper_trail-enabled model fail silently?

Tags: postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, paper-trail-gem

Rails 5.0.0, Heroku Postgres 9.6.1

```
m = MyModel.create(foo: 'bar')
=> #<MyModel foo: 'bar'>
m.foo = nil
=> nil
m.save
=> true
m.reload
=> #<MyModel foo: 'bar'>
m.foo
=> 'bar'
```

How might this happen?

Comment: Actually, it turns out that Step 2 is not working, as you suggest. Step 2 returns `true` (as does `.save!`), but if I reload m, `m.foo` is still `'bar'`. 

Comment: The issue appears to stem from [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail). If I remove it from my model, everything works as expected. I'm not sure how to track down the issue.

Comment: You might find our [bug report template](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/doc/bug_report_template.rb) useful for isolating the issue. Hope it helps!

Comment: @JaredBeck I think that it's related to the use of uuids. I've abandoned the gem for now, but thanks. 